# What are lawyers who work with FCC regulations called?

Tags: united-states, lawyer, fcc

I have a question about FCC regulations, and would like an answer from a lawyer. How would I find a lawyer familiar with this topic?

Answer (score 3):

The broad area is called [*communications law*](https://www.americanbar.org/groups/communications_law/). The [ABA links to state bar search tools](https://www.americanbar.org/groups/legal_services/flh-home/flh-bar-directories-and-lawyer-finders/) to help you find a lawyer in that area. Some states (e.g. Oregon) do not have one of those search-by-practice-area tools, but they may have an alternative like a [lawyer referral service](https://www.osbar.org/public/ris).

Comment: Regulatory law and administrative law would also be common specialties dealing with these kinds of issues.